# Forward specific domain to directory?

Tags: .htaccess, domain

If I have 2 domains, *altoonadesign.com* and *programming-perils.com* that are both pointed to the same server.

How can I make programming-perils site root the `blog` folder on the real site root. and disallow access to the `blog` folder from altoonadesign.com using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a leap and assume you're using Apache.  You'll want to set up separate VirtualHost blocks for each site (or different site files each containing a virtualhost block, however you're comfortable), and set them to have different DocumentRoots.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName altoonadesign.com
    ServerAlias www.altoonadesign.com
    ...
    <Directory /var/www>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/blog>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
    ServerName programming-perils.com
    ServerAlias www.programming-perils.com
    ...
    <Directory /var/www/blog>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

A better option (so you don't need the /blog in place) may be to move the blog files outside of the tree that contains the other site.

Comment: +1 Thanks, also is there a way to do this using just .htaccess?

Comment: @John Yes, but it would have to be a rather terrifying mess of RewriteRules (with RewriteConds determining the domain).  It would not be pleasant ;)